# LINQ on EF generated class

Tags: linq, entity-framework, class, generated

I have this classes on EF from database

```
public partial class STUDENT
{
    public short STUDENTID { get; set; }
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    public string FAMILY { get; set; }

    public virtual CLASS CLASS { get; set; }
}

public partial class CLASS
{
    public CLASS()
    {
        this.STUDENTs = new HashSet<STUDENT>();
    }

    public short CLASSID { get; set; }
    public string CLASSNAME { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<STUDENT> STUDENTs { get; set; }
}

public partial class VALIDNAMES
{
    public string VALIDNAME { get; set; }
}
```

I want force user can't insert any data on student.name that this name is not on VALIDNAMES recordes.
I want do this in model layer because I want use name property on many pages therefore I want have this validation on this layer.

In other-hand I want use LINQ on model layer or is possible change set and get for EF generated classes?

Comment: You can make setters private.

Answer (score 0):

You can try set a foreign key constraint on the NAME column in your STUDENT table that reference the VALIDNAME column of VALIDNAMES table.

Assuming you are using SQL Server, you need to execute something like this against your database :

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[STUDENT]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_student_valid_name] FOREIGN KEY([NAME])
REFERENCES [dbo].[VALIDNAMES] ([VALIDNAME])
GO
```

You may also need to specify the [STUDENT].[NAME] column as `NOT NULL` (so your user cannot enter `NULL` names), and set the [VALIDNAMES].[VALIDNAME] as unique index / primary key.

This way, the validation is done by the DBMS instead of your application code.

Comment: OK, thanks but my question is public for using linq on EF generated class for validation. for example I have a function on database and get id parameter and return Boolean result, I want only persons can update student table records that this function return true.

Comment: Your original question didn't mention anything about calling db function, is that what you are really trying to achieve?

Comment: I want use LINQ in set section of property to retrieve a value according special condition and only allow value set for that value